# Leaflet problems .js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I copy the code from the leafletjs's web.

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
.openPopup();
```

But then my code that before work with any problems. Alert that an addEventListener return "null".

```js
(function(){
"use strict";
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

//Here is the code from leafletjs.

  //In the middle have code like "getElementById"
    
 calcular.addEventListener('click', calcularMontos);
 
 });
})();
```

And I don't know how to repare the error, the ID calcularMontos isn't from the index.hmtl.

Comment: Well, this seems like:
var calcular = document.getElementById('calcular'); the id "calcular" isn't in the index.html. And that make an error when I enter in index.html when I go to the HTML that has the id, that error don't exist.

With the map in index.html generate error in all the html.

Plus sorry for my english.